# I tried changing everything in AndroidManifest.xml file but still unable to upload the bundle app in Google play console

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

```
**MY AndroidManifest.xml file:**
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.usa">
   <application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

            <!-- <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
              android:value="myapp"
              /> -->
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem first :

```
android:exported="true"
```

then  upgraded Gradle to :

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
}
```

lastly on app gradle changed :

```
android {
    
compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "appid"
        minSdkVersion 20
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. First I updated the Gradle package and kept the minSdkVersion to 21. But while building the app it asks me to add the activity for (Stripe payment) which I have used in my app, later added the activity for the Stripe payment with android:exported="true" and also removed the Intent filter too in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Finally, after all these, my app got built and I uploaded it to the play store. Thank you so much for your support, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

if you use facebook authentication so please change this in app level build.gradle

\android\app\build.gradle

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

to

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.+'

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:exported="true"`

```dart
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.usa">
   <application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

            <!-- <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
              android:value="myapp"
              /> -->
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: tried that bro still not working

Answer (score 0):

- Open your project in Android Studio.
- Open your AndroidManifest.xml file.
- And click "Merged Manifest"
- Check for libraries that don't use "android:exported".
- And add if you need.

[image]